# Json-server. Помощь сформировать запрос, чтобы получить нужный массив данных

Tags: javascript, json, axios

Есть такой json-файл:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "id": 0,
   "comments": [
    {
     "id": 0,
     "text": "text"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

data массив объектов, у которых есть свойство comments.
json-server при запросе http://localhost:3001/data/1 дает первый объект этого массива, первый пост, а мне нужно у первого поста получить только комментарии (в последствии чтобы также добавлять и удалять их). Как сформировать запрос? Я изучал документацию и не раз, но или там этого нет, или я тупой.

localhost:3001/data/1/comments не работает, возвращает пустой объект.

UPD: json-server это библиотека для автоматического создания сервера, все что я делал для его настройки - это запихал в него мой файл json. У него есть стандартные запросы npmjs.com/package/json-server

Единственное решение которое я придумал - создать после даты еще комменты, и привязывать по айди их друг к другу. Запросы с фильтрами делать там можно. Но код уже написан по старой дб, изменений много нужно будет вносить.

Comment: Ну это же ваш сервер, кто же его знает, какие параметры принимает, как обрабатывает и что возвращает... Покажите код серверной части, которая формирует вам ответ(может там вообще не предусмотрено возвращать только комментарии. И отдельно, что вам мешает из полученных данных забрать комментарии и работать с ними?

Comment: json-server это библиотека для автоматического создания сервера, все что я делал для его настройки - это запихал в него мой файл json. У него есть стандартные запросы, вот https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server , но не могу понять по документации как создать запрос на комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `localhost:3001/data/1/comments` не работает, возвращает пустой объект

Если верить документации https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server Такое сработает только при другой структуре данных. Например такой

```
{
 "data": [
    {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "просто для примера"
    }
 ]
 "comments": [
    {
     "id": 0,
     "text": "text",
     "dataId": 0
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Да, это видимо единственно возможное решение. Спасибо.